# setup-cron. ERROR: zend-opcache missing

Tags: magento2, cron, opcache

Recently we have discovered the problem in magento 2.1.8

When this command runs:

```
php bin/magento setup:cron:run
```

it logs error in log :

```
[2017-09-08 07:24:02] setup-cron.ERROR: Following required PHP extensions are missing:  zend-opcache [] []
```

I've confirmed that opcache is installed :
[image: screen shot]

Comment: Do you use apache or nginx end which version of php?

Comment: nginx + varnish 
but its related to cli ... not FPM @KyryloRomantsov

Comment: try this guide http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/enable-php-5-5-opcache-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: You have this problem because OPcache extension in disabled on your server